# Virtual Machine in 'VMware Fusion 2' won't detect DVD drive

Tags: windows-7, bios, vmware-fusion

My current setup is a first-gen MacBookPro with a broken DVD drive (taken out).

I'm using an external USB DVD drive which is confirmed to be functional (can mount and read) on both the Macbook using Mac OSX and another PC.

I have a student version of Windows 7 on DVD and also as a image file (all official, confirmed working on another PC).

I am trying to install Windows 7 with VMware Fusion 2. I create a virtual machine as Windows Server 2008 and when the VM boots, it doesn't detect the DVD drive.

VMware correctly detects and is set to use the DVD drive, but the VM doesn't have it (checked the BIOS, it can detect new hard drives made by Fusion, but no DVD drive). It just goes straight to network boot (even with the boot sequence of CDROM, removable, hard drive, network)

I tried this with the external DVD drive and the image file of the DVD. I have also tried installing Windows XP and confirmed that it is the DVD drive is not being detected.

Anyone know how to fix this or have experience with this?

Comment: I now have the bios recognizing a cdrom drive (fed by VMware from the usb dvd drive). The problem is now why VMware is detecting a DVD drive, but the bios is detecting a CD drive

Comment: Ok everyone, I got the problem. The version I have of Windows 7 (off MSDNNA) wasn't bootable... or wasn't burned as a bootable. Figured this out by trying out a Vista DVD.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments to the question, this was solved:

> The version I have of Windows 7 (off MSDNNA) wasn't bootable... or wasn't burned as a bootable. Figured this out by trying out a Vista DVD.